# can't connect to jenkins using ldap users

Tags: jenkins

I'm using jenkins and I would like to use ldap users to connect to jenkins. I put all informations in *security configuration* --> *LDAP* and I click on the *Apply* button, after that the connection to ldap is ok but when I register it and come back again in security configuration, I see this message :

> Unable to connect to 10.26.56.70:10389 : javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: ERR_229 Cannot authenticate user ]

It looks like jenkins can't autommatically connect to LDAP server. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you forgot or have misconfigured the fields "Manager DN" and "Manager Password". The Manager DN is the account for reading the LDAP database when other users are authenticating so it needs full access to the database.

Comment: thks for your answer ! I did it : Manager DN = uid=admin,ou=system and I gave the password but I don't understand

Comment: Does this reflect your LDAP schema? Or did you just copy it from the Internet?

Comment: when I apply the connection is ok the matter is when I come back I got this error

Comment: @aiche I'm not sure it is necessary to specify the Manager DN in a fully qualified way. I simply provide the actual username.

Comment: you mean juste 'admin' ?

Comment: I think the problem is that ldap use a specific hash code for password and it isn't conform to jenkins hash code...